# Test if PHP variable is anonymous function

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to test if a variable is an anonymous function/callback. Using the PHP.net example:

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
```

You could call it with:

```
$greet('hi');
```

But what if $greet could be some other variable type and you only want to execute the callback if it's set to a function? Something like:

```
is_func($greet);
is_callback($greet);
is_callable($greet);
```

Am I missing something in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_callable($greet)` will do that.

Also:

`($greet instanceof Closure)` might work.

Comment: ha, dammit. of course, I use it in my own example. did not see it linked in the docs for anon functions. must've missed it. thanks!